# android show multi point on esri map

Tags: android, dictionary, arcgis

I am new developer in an arcgis environment and I'm also an android developer. For my training I followed the arcgis tutorials. I want add multi point on my map, but when I try, only the last point appears on the map.
I need your help to solve it.

Here is my current code:

```
 MapView mMapview;
  GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_map);
        mMapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapview.addLayer(graphicsLayer);

        SimpleMarkerSymbol sms = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED,10, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CIRCLE);

        MultiPoint multiPoint =  new MultiPoint();
        multiPoint.add(-5.2769,6.8169);
        multiPoint.add(-3.0195,8.7057);
        multiPoint.add(-0.0195,9.7057);


        int len = multiPoint.getPointCount();
        Graphic[] graphics = new Graphic[len];
        for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
            Point pt = multiPoint.getPoint(i);
            graphics[i] = new Graphic(pt,sms);
           graphicsLayer.addGraphic(graphics[i]);
        }
        //graphicsLayer.addGraphics(graphics);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Count "+graphicsLayer.getNumberOfGraphics(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me using ArcGIS Runtime 10.2.4, but I have to zoom in very far to see the three distinct points because the coordinates are in meters if you're using one of the standard ArcGIS basemaps. Maybe that's your problem. If those values are supposed to be longitude and latitude instead, you have to project them, and you can only do that after the `MapView` has been initialized, which you can do using an `OnStatusChangedListener`. Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_map);
    mMapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapview.addLayer(graphicsLayer);

    final SimpleMarkerSymbol sms = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
            Color.RED, 10, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CIRCLE);

    final MultiPoint multiPoint =  new MultiPoint();
    multiPoint.add(-5.2769,6.8169);
    multiPoint.add(-3.0195,8.7057);
    multiPoint.add(-0.0195,9.7057);

    final int len = multiPoint.getPointCount();
    final Graphic[] graphics = new Graphic[len];
    mMapview.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {
        public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
            if (STATUS.INITIALIZED.equals(status)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    Point pt = multiPoint.getPoint(i);
                    pt = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(
                            pt.getX(),
                            pt.getY(),
                            mMapview.getSpatialReference());
                    graphics[i] = new Graphic(pt,sms);
                    graphicsLayer.addGraphic(graphics[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //graphicsLayer.addGraphics(graphics);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Count "+graphicsLayer.getNumberOfGraphics(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

FYI if you prefer, you can create a single graphic with the `MultiPoint` geometry, instead of the three graphics you are creating with `Point` geometries now. Once again, you would need to project the `MultiPoint` to the map's spatial reference.